# Problem: Output of plm Package Dummy Variables with Additional 1

Tags: output, summary, dummy-variable, plm

i have a strange output when using the plm package to do a pooled OLS regression.

The dummy variables, D_1, D_2, D_3 and D_4, are displayed in the output and in the summary with an additional 1.

Can someone tell me where this 1 comes from and how to get rid of it?

Thanks a lot [image]

Comment: This is "standard R" behaviour: The non-base levels of a factor are given in the output. Likely you coded your levels as `0` and `1`. Had you coded them `no` and `yes` you would see `D_1yes` (assuming `yes` is the non-base level). In case there are more than two levels, you would see additional `D_1xxx` entries.

Comment: Thank you Helix123.  In my cas they appeared out of the blue after an update. Am I right in assuming that they are displayed like this by default?

Comment: I speculate you treated the variable as numeric variables before, maybe due to the way you imported the data and that way could have change by a package update or so. This is the default for factor variables, yes.